# React and CSP - EvalError: call to Function() blocked by CSP

Tags: reactjs, npm, content-security-policy, react-pdf

I'm using react-pdf to generate PDF files in my React application.
Since today I was using 'unsafe-eval' in the CSP, but this no option for my project any longer. Removing 'unsafe-eval' for scripts leads to this error in the restructure library which is a dependency of react-pdf:

```
 if (this.options.relativeTo) {
      this.relativeToGetter = new Function('ctx', "return ctx." + this.options.relativeTo);
 }
```

I already checked their Github-Repo, a corresponding thread is still open and remains unresolved since 2 years.

Are there any solutions I can do instead of hopefully waiting for an react-pdf update? One possibility would be to use another library, but completely rewriting my project would cause a lot of effort.

Is there any way to edit the CSP header just to allow unsafe-eval for this library?

Answer (score 0):

`'unsafe-eval'` acts as a global page flag, so there is no way to allow it for some scripts only.

But [issue](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/816) you refers was [fixed](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/2282) since version 0.2.0 of `pdfmake`.
You have to update dependencies manually or wait a common node.js updates.

Note: this topic/issue is about `bpampuch/pdfmake` (please see a [specific piece of script code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68557489/react-and-csp-evalerror-call-to-function-blocked-by-csp) at startpost), it's **not related** other PDF libs, for instance `diegomura/react-pdf`.

Comment: for me this does not solve the problem... I still get `Uncaught EvalError`. I am using `"@react-pdf/renderer": "2.0.17"`

Comment: *To Neneil*: This topic relates `bpampuch/pdfmake` library. How it could solve an issue with a different `diegomura/react-pdf` libs you do use? You particular issue is mentioned [here](https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/510) and [here](https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/238). You can dig these issues or to fill a [Pull Request](https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/pulls) to a library support team

Comment: Do you know any good alternatives to create pdfs with react? `unsafe-eval` is not an solution for me.

Comment: Weird question in the topic about `pampuch/pdfmake` library which announces to be free of 'unsafe-eval', isn't it? But first you should to locate the issue in your `diegomura/react-pdf` - what piece of code requires 'unsafe-eval' (Dev tool should show that). Maybe there is a workaround in your case.